# syntax to display in web page

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

Hi I am preparing web application. I want to display Title in web page . I have prepared code in Visual Studio 2012.

while Compiling Error: "TextBox and Label" are not known element is the above syntax is correct.

```
<table>

  <tr>

    <td style="width: 120px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top" class="blue">Title
      <asp:label ID="Title" runat="server" Text="*" CssClass="error" Visible="false"></asp:label>
    </td>

    <td>
      <asp: Textbox runat="server" ID="txtTitle" style="width: 200px" CssClass="control"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

let me know if anything wrong

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can we see some source code? It sounds like you're defining elements outside of the scope of the program?

Comment: Post your code behind where you are hitting the error.

Comment: Code added.... Is the code Correct to dispay "Title" in web page as output

Comment: for asp did you mean to write "=" instead of ":"?

Comment: Can you please check what code I written is correct do u want to do some changes in it....if not suggest the correct code or syntax

Comment: What exact error are you receiving ?

Comment: currently: "<asp: Textbox...." change to <asp="Textbox".... ? Same for the <asp:label

Comment: @user2977578 - What ? Thats not how the syntax works for .NET controls. That would be incorrect.

Comment: @sai - Can you show us the exact error that you are receiving ?

Comment: sorry, disregard my comments, I was focused on the html part

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application (ERROR)

Comment: @MattMurdock can u suggest the correct code.....

Comment: @sai in your `webconfig` under `controls` can you see  `<add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls">` ?? confim me what are the namespace seen under `controls`  tag

Comment: @sai - If that's the error, then most probably its an issue related to your URL routes. Can you post a screenshot of the error window ?

Comment: @Webruster i dint find what u ask in web config can i have aother suggestion

Comment: @sai can i have a screenshot of your webconfig atleast ?

Comment: I dint prepare code yet in web config

Comment: @Webruster can I get code to display "Title "with text box  length 100px" in asp.net

Comment: @sai what exactly you want ? in your question asking to solve the error but in comment you asking for code !! bit confused , can you elaborate more to help you out

Comment: because if you dint get the error correctly because I dont have option to display error properly because I am using remote login thats why I am asking can I have the exact code so that I can edit my code

Comment: @sai see are you asking you want to show a text in text box or value of your label in text box ?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the extra space in between `asp: Textbox`

try like this

```
<asp:Textbox runat="server" ID="txtTitle" style="width: 200px" CssClass="control"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I guess you have inserted the above code within <title> </title> tag of html. is it?

Comment: No I have used <table></table>

Answer (score 0):

I think this was the error you are facing
[image]

If this is the error you are facing then you have to remove the code from `<title>` and add the same code within `<body>` tag.
Like this

```html
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  
    <table>
     <tr>
        <td style="width: 120px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top" class="blue">Title
          <asp:label ID="Title" runat="server" Text="*" CssClass="error" Visible="false"></asp:label>
        </td>

        <td>
          <asp:Textbox runat="server" ID="txtTitle" style="width: 200px" CssClass="control"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the HTML and .net both are same

Comment: Thanku all for your answers!!